# DynamoDb database design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm new to DynamoDb and noSql in general.

I have a `users` table and a `notes` table. A user can create notes and I want to be able to retrieve all notes associated with a user.

One solution I've thought of is every time a note is saved the note id is stored inside a 'notes' attribute inside the user table. This will allow me to query the users table for all note id's and then query notes using those id's:

```
UserTable:
UserId: 123456789
notes: ['note-id-1', note-id-2]

NotesTable
id: note-id-1
text: "Some note"
```

Is this the correct approach? The only other way I can think is to have the notes table have a `userId` attribute so I can then query the notes table based on that userId. Obviously this is the sort of approach is more relational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take the approach at the end of your question: each note should have a userId attribute. Then create a global secondary index with `userId` as primary key and `noteId` as sort key. This way you can also query on userId, by doing a query on that index.

If you do it the way you suggested, you always need two queries to get the notes of a user (first get the notes from the user table and then query on the notes table). Also, when someone has N notes you would need to do N queries, this is going to be expensive if N is large.

If you do it the way in this answer, you need one query to get all notes of a user (I'm assuming no pagination) and one to get the user information. Will never be more than 2.

General rule of thumb:

- SQL: storage = expensive, computation = cheap
- NoSQL: storage = cheap, computation = expensive

So always try to need as little queries as possible.

Comment: Thanks Luc, My eyes have been opened to the world of secondary indexes!